# Upload File into a Custom object and save into File related list

Tags: visualforce, files

Need to upload a file in a VF page and the file should save in the Files related list of the Custom Object.

Have tried with the following code but it is saving in the File object with no parent. Need to save the file into a Custom object

```
public class ContentController {
    public blob file { get; set; }

    public PageReference upload() {
        ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
        v.versionData = file;
        v.title = 'testing upload';
        v.pathOnClient ='/somepath.txt';
        insert v;
        return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the Content Document Link in order to link the file to the record.
Also, you need to query the ContentDocument Id after you insert the content version.

```
Id conDocument = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:v.Id].ContentDocumentId;
//Insert ContentDocumentLink
ContentDocumentLink cDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
cDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDocument;//Add ContentDocumentId
cDocLink.LinkedEntityId = attach.ParentId;//Add attachment parentId
cDocLink.ShareType = 'I';//V - Viewer permission. C - Collaborator permission. I - Inferred permission.
cDocLink.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';//AllUsers, InternalUsers, SharedUsers
Insert cDocLink;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) afterwards in order to link the file to a record.